# no such method: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()ILoggerFactory/invokeVirtual in C#/docx4j.NET

Tags: c#, docx4j

I've found a number of hits regarding this message in java/Maven, but I'm using C#/VisualStudio so their answers don't directly apply.  The project is C#, .NET 4.5 Console project where I used nuget:

```
install-package doc4j.net
```

I have this snippet of code:

```
    try
    {
        string projectDir = @"C:\project\samples\";
        ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        log.Info("Hello from Common Logging");
        System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)); 

        ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
                typeof(org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder))); 

        // Configure to find docx4j.properties
        // .. add as URL the dir containing docx4j.properties (not the file itself!)
        Plutext.PropertiesConfigurator.setDocx4jPropertiesDir(@"C:\project\samples\resources\");

        fileIN = projectDir + @"P0009.docx";
        java.io.File javaFile = new java.io.File(fileIN);
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordDoc = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(javaFile); // Exception occurs here.

        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.getMainDocumentPart();
        Console.WriteLine(mainPart.getXML());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

At the commented line, I get and exception:

```
Message=The type initializer for 'org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage' threw an exception.
```

The inner-most exception is this:

```
Message=no such method: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()ILoggerFactory/invokeVirtual
Source=IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
```

All the posts I've found say there's a version mismatch involving slf4j, and the solution is to modify the vom.xml to control the dependencies.  Since this is VisualStudio, obviously that isn't the answer.  Not only that, but looking at the documented dependencies and versions installed in the project, (docx4j v3.3.2.81, IKVM v8.1.5717.0, Common.Logging v2.1.2.0 and slf4j v1.7.5.4) that shouldn't apply anyway.  So the question is simple: How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? (I'm having the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you comment out the following, it appears to work:

```
    //ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
        //System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
           //typeof(org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)));
```